# Seamless adjacent shapes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path

Is there a convenient way to take two shapes in Inkscape and cut the border of one to follow the border of the other?

Basically, if I have two overlapping shapes, I'd like to have Inkscape delete the overlapping portion of *one* shape while leaving the other untouched. Path > Exclusion doesn't do this, as it deletes the overlapping portion of both (and merges the shapes into one); Path > Division and Path > Cut Path don't do this as they delete one of the shapes entirely.

I'm able to copy the shape I'd like unchanged, line it up perfectly with the original, and use that to do Path > Division (and then delete the leftover bit), but it's a clunky solution. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Sjiveru, have you tried to use [tiled Clones](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tiled-Clones) (like [here](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic3a5d.html?t=31907) for example)? Can you tell us something more about your efforts?

Answer (score 1):

Path operations usually delete one of the paths.

The usual way, instead of copy and pasting one of the paths, is to use *Duplicate*, which has a nice keybinding (<kbd>Ctrl D</kbd>). This will leave a copy in the same place, already selected.

Shift-select the other path, and perform the path operation.